# How to use the variable of one method in another method in Java(android)

Tags: java, android, methods, scope

I am retrieving the value of a TextView like this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calculation);
    TextView heading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.paper_name);
    ......
}
```

I have another method in same class

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {   
    int BLACK_AND_WHITE_MULTIUPLIER = 4200;
    int COLOR_MULTIUPLIER = 6400;
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btCalculate:
        int multiplier = rbColor.isChecked() ? COLOR_MULTIUPLIER : BLACK_AND_WHITE_MULTIUPLIER;
        int column = Integer.parseInt((String) spColumn.getSelectedItem());
        int inch = Integer.parseInt((String) spInch.getSelectedItem());
        tvAmount.setText((multiplier * column * inch) + "");
        break;
    }
}
```

I want to set the value of `COLOR_MULTIUPLIER` and `BLACK_AND_WHITE_MULTIUPLIER` based on value of **heading** which I have got from the onCreate method. Is it possible?

Comment: Declare your TextView `heading` outside of the `onCreate` method. Inside of `onCreate` you assign it a value. Now your `onClick` method can access the varaible `heading`.

Comment: You should use global variable heading should be global, not local. Declare TextView heading in class

Comment: Do you mean getting the value of the textview and transforming it to an "int" so you can set it to your "MULTIUPLIERS"?

Comment: @Takendarkk : I have two integer variable LACK_AND_WHITE_MULTIUPLIER and COLOR . I want to change the value of those two variables based on heading .

Comment: As it is now those 2 variables are declared, initialized, and only accessible inside of the `onClick` method. Perhaps make them global variables like my answer says you should do with `heading`. That way, if you make any changes, they will be visible after you exit the `onClick` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your `TextView` at class level...

```
TextView heading;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calculation);

        heading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.paper_name);
        heading.setText("something");

            ......
```

then access it in `onClick()` method as below...

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{   
     int BLACK_AND_WHITE_MULTIUPLIER = 4200;
     int COLOR_MULTIUPLIER = 6400;
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btCalculate:

            int multiplier = 0;

            if (heading.getText().toString.equals("something")) {

                multiplier = COLOR_MULTIUPLIER;

            } else {

                multiplier = BLACK_AND_WHITE_MULTIUPLIER;

            }

            //int multiplier = rbColor.isChecked() ? COLOR_MULTIUPLIER
            //        : BLACK_AND_WHITE_MULTIUPLIER;
            int column = Integer.parseInt((String) spColumn
                    .getSelectedItem());
            int inch = Integer.parseInt((String) spInch.getSelectedItem());
            tvAmount.setText((multiplier * column * inch) + "");
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `TextView heading;` so that it is a class variable not a local variable and then it will be accessible throughout your whole class.

It can then be intialized in `onCreate` and read and or updated in `onClick`

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216633/how-to-use-the-variable-of-one-method-in-another-method-in-javaandroid#comment33731363_22216633), you just need to make `heading` a variable that belongs to the whole object, not just the `onCreate` method. You do this in the following way.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    TextView heading;  //Declared outside of onCreate

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        heading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.paper_name); //Assigned inside of onCreate
    }
}
```

Then that variable becomes accessible inside your `onClick`

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    heading.getText(); //Or whatever you need to use it for
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare your TextView heading outside of the onCreate method i.e. at class level. Inside  onCreate assign it a value and Now in onClick method can access the varaible heading and get it's value.